# MapView - icons placed on top of each other

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a google map in react-native. On top of that View I have icons on the map, and these icons are placed on top of each other instead of being placed on either side of the map. I have tried many different settings but it always end up the same. Another thing is that the button reacts when I'm not clicking on it.

I have container and then mapview within the container. Here's the code:

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
},
map:{
    height: 90+ "%",
    flexDirection: 'column'
},
profileBtn:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 25,
    right: 30,
    width: 25,
    height: 15,
    borderRadius: 25/2,
},
homeBtn:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    left: 5,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 25/2,
},

<MapView
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={{
        latitude:this.state.latitude,
        longitude:this.state.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0043,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0034
    }}
    ref={c => this.mapView = c}
    onPress={this.onMapPress}
    loadingEnabled={true}
>
    <View style ={styles.topMap}>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.profileBtn}
            onPress={()=>{ this.handleClickProfile() }}
        >
            <Image
                source={profile}
                borderRadius={17}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.homeBtn}
            onPress={()=>{ this.handleClickFavourite() }}
        >
            <Image
                source={require("./home.png")}
                borderRadius={49}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    {markers}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code for `MapView` ?

Comment: Added it to op. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why this would happen, but I read the source code from [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/components/MapView.js), when you display a `MapView`, this gets returned:

```
return (
    <AIRMap
        ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
        {...props}
    />
)
```

Normally, when you write a custom view, you would do it this way:

```
return (
    <AIRMap
        ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
        {...props}
    >
        {children}
    </AIRMap>
)
```

Maybe that's why your `MapView`'s children don't get rendered the way you want it to. However, to solve the problem, you can simply move the views out of `MapView`, then wrap everything in a `View`:

```
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}>
            {markers}
        </MapView>
        <TouchableOpacity ... />
        <TouchableOpacity ... />
    </View>
)
```

But remember, all those `TouchableOpacity`'s must have `position: 'absolute'`, or else your `MapView` won't take up the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are getting added one over the other because you have used `position:absolute` for the buttons.If you are intenting to use markers over map do it this way

```
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

<MapView
  region={this.state.region}
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>
  {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
    <Marker
      coordinate={marker.latlng}
      title={marker.title}
      description={marker.description}
    />
  ))}
</MapView>
```

And visit [this](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps#rendering-a-list-of-markers-on-a-map) for more info